# используя цикл for пройти все елементы

Tags: javascript

при каждом клике добавлять елементу красный цвет, когда все елементы будут красного цвета, то по одному клику с конца возвращать елеметам черный цвет, как это можно сделать?
html:

```
<ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="btn">click</button>
```

JS:

```
function ready() {
    var i = 0;
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
        var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i; i < list.length;) {
            list[i].style.color = "red";
            i++;
            return;
        }
    };
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Условиями и проверкой стилей:

```js
var list = document.querySelector('ul'),
    item = list.querySelectorAll('li');

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var itemRed = list.querySelectorAll('li[style*="color: red"]');
  // Проверяем, все ли элементы крассные (количество красных li и всего сколько li)
  if(itemRed.length == item.length){
    //Если да, то удаляем color у элемента
    for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
      item[i].style.color = '';
    };
  }else{
    // Если нет, то красим следующий элемент в красный (itemRed.length использщуем, как индекс следующего)
    item[itemRed.length].style.color = 'red';
  };
};
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

**UPDATA**:

```js
var list = document.querySelector('ul'),
    item = list.querySelectorAll('li');

list.status = false; // Присваиваем свойство
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var itemRed = list.querySelectorAll('li[style*="color: red"]');
  // Проверяем, все ли элементы крассные (количество красных li и всего сколько li) или проверяем статус списка
  if(itemRed.length == item.length || list.status == true){
    //Если да, то удаляем color у последнего элемента
    item[itemRed.length - 1].style.color = '';
    
    // Проверяем, закончились ли красные
    if(itemRed.length == 1){
      list.status = false; // Если да, то меняем статус
    }else{
      list.status = true; // Если нет, то снова назначаем true
    };
  }else{
    // Если нет, то красим следующий элемент в красный (itemRed.length использщуем, как индекс следующего)
    item[itemRed.length].style.color = 'red';
  };
};
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: а как сделать чтобы по одному елементу менялся на с красного на черный(с конца)?

Comment: @DimaVleskov, т.е. до красного, а потом обратно в чёрное?

Comment: да, но только с когда 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: @DimaVleskov, обновил

Comment: спасибо, выручил